# Laravel queue listen returns var_dump of $this

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, amazon-sqs

When I run any command like listen, or work, or anything else, I get a 30mb dump of data (I think it's the $this variable

One command that I run, where I get that dump is:
`php artisan queue:listen --timeout=30 --tries=1`

Basically this returns something like: (this is truncated, since like I said its 30mb)

```
  ["this"]=>
  object(Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider)#212 (1) {
    ["app":protected]=>
    object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)#5 (32) {
      ["basePath":protected]=>
      string(12) "/var/www/sst"
      ["hasBeenBootstrapped":protected]=>
      bool(true)
      ["booted":protected]=>
      bool(true)
      ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(Closure)#148 (1) {
          ["this"]=>
          object(Clockwork\DataSource\LaravelDataSource)#143 (7) {
            ["app":protected]=>
            *RECURSION*
            ["response":protected]=>
            NULL
            ["log":protected]=>
            object(Clockwork\Request\Log)#147 (2) {
              ["data"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["collectStackTraces":protected]=>
              bool(true)
            }
            ["timeline":protected]=>
            object(Clockwork\Request\Timeline)#144 (1) {
```

Comment: check your project for a call to `dd` or `dump`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `dd()` somewhere in a `boot()` or `__construct()` method somewhere in your application.

These methods are called before any `php artisan` command is run.

My suggestion would be to use your editor to search your `App/Console` directory for `dd(`